# deprecated product type 'com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp' for 'iOS'. WatchKit 1.0 is no longer supported

Tags: ios, watchkit

Please help to fix the below error:

I am migrating a Xcode project from Xcode 8 to Xcode 10, but I am getting the below error, the application supports WatchKit extension as well.

Error:

> deprecated product type 'com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp' for 'iOS'. WatchKit 1.0 is no longer supported. (in target 'Appname WatchKit App').

Answer (score 1):

WatchKit 1.0 is no longer supported. From [Submitting watchOS Apps to the App Store](https://developer.apple.com/watchos/submit/) at the bottom of the page:

> As of April 1, 2018, updates to watchOS 1 apps will no longer be accepted. All updates must be native apps built with the watchOS 2 SDK or later.

Go to your project settings, then your WatchKit extension scheme, then bump the deployment target.